# Oracle timestamp sql query

Tags: oracle, datetime

I have stored TIMESTAMP attribute in the database in the following format:
11/17/2014 3:00:00 PM 
11/17/2014 4:00:00 PM 
etc...
I am trying to query for all records ( I stored 30 days) where hour is 3:00 PM.

```
Select * from DaysTb where timeOfday =to_date('11/17/2014 3:00:00 PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh12:00')
```

however, my query is incorrect. Googling did not help me to find an answer. 
I would appreciate some guidance. 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the timestamp attribute is stored as a STRING in the database? or as a true TIMESTAMP data type? If it is the latter (and I hope it is), it is NOT stored in the format you show - that is a string format, not a timestamp "format."  Also, when you say 3:00 PM, do you mean exactly 3:00:00, or any time between 3:00:00 and 3:59:59? By the way, to find out the data type of your columns, you can try DESCRIBE DAYSTB if you use sqlplus (or Toad or SQL Developer).

Comment: The data are stored as TIMESTAMP.  With my co-worker help, I used Extract with HOUR and was able to query all the records within a month where hour equals to 3:00 PM.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct Oracle SQL statement

```
select *  from yourTableName where 
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM data_date ) = 15;
```

It returns all the records with 15:00 o'clock stamp.